# symfony2 entities data not persisted

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, relation

I'm trying to persist a new entity, a "member", which has a contact field. The contact field is another entity, composed of a mail and a phone field. When I try to persist a new member, I add an email and a phone number, but the phone is not persisted. I did a var_dump over the object in my controller, and I found out that the `private phone => null` but doctrine added a new attribute : `public phones => <the actual phone number>`. This attribute doesnt exist in my entity.. What did I do wrong ? the relation between member and contact is

`@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Interne\FichierBundle\Entity\Contact", cascade={"persist", "remove"})`

Thanks a lot for your help

EDIT :

result of the var_dump over my"member", for the contact entry :

```
private 'contact' =>
object(Interne\FichierBundle\Entity\Contact)[891]
  private 'id' => null
  private 'telephone' => null
  private 'email' => string 'test@gmail.com' (length=25)
  public 'telephones' => float 2187187392749
```

As you can see, telephone is empty, but telephones isnt. Problem is, there are no telephones attribute in my entities.

Comment: you need to post your entities.

Comment: just edited, but my entities are quite big

Comment: what's even weirder is that telephones is public, is it possible that it's an inherited field?

Comment: Can you post the code where you fill your member entity and try to persist it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your setter is not ok. Please check that your `telephone setter` method is:

```
 public function setTelephone($telephone)
 {
      $this->telephone = $telephone;
 }
```

Comment: Yep thanks, actually, the doctrine:generate:entities didnt do the job correctly !